# Extend row-level security to a bridging table

Tags: sql-server, database, row-level-security

I am working on row level security in my database. I have two tables. Row based security is implemented on data_table and only returns rows that the user can see.

data_table:

```
data_id    name        role
-----------------------------
1          test        USER
2          another     ADMIN
3          yep         USER
```

type_table:

```
type_id    name
-----------------
1          this
2          is
3          a
4          type
```

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'USER';
SELECT * FROM data_table;
```

returns rows 1 and 3 only. If you execute as ADMIN, all of the rows are returned. This is working properly in my database.

However, my issue is my bridging table.

data_type_table:

```
data_type_id    data_id    type_id
1               1          2
2               1          3
3               2          1
4               2          2
5               3          1
6               3          4
```

As of right now

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'USER';
SELECT COUNT(data_type_id) FROM data_type_table;
```

returns 6 because it's looking at all 6 rows in the table. I'm trying to set it up in such a way that user USER will only see rows in data_type_table which are referencing rows where data_table.role = 'USER' (this means that the select count query would return 4). What would be the simplest way to implement something like this?

My data_table will more than likely contain hundreds of thousands of rows. Efficiency could become a problem here.

Comment: `JOIN` the query to your other table.

Comment: My only concern with that is that my tables could potentially have hundreds of thousands of rows of data. Having to run a join every time a select is performed on the bridge table could slow things up a lot.

Comment: Then you'd have to introduce the same row level security to the table.